# Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'string' Error

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, observable

Soy nuevo trabajando con angular, nodejs, tengo que crear un CRUD de archivos txt local (leerlos desde una dirección local y mostrar su contenido en un P).
Mi problema es que tengo un metodo que me retorna el contenido del archivo

Mi document service: 
aqui extraigo los datos con el ligandolo con el nodejs

En vez de obtener los datos el parrafo se cambia a Object [Object] si es que lo convierto a string, fuera de ahi me popea el error de Observable

```
  readonly URL_API = 'http://localhost:3000/documents'; //mi direccion que obtiene los nombres de los archivos (los txt)

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) {
      this.documentSelected = new Document();
   }

  getDocuments(){
    console.log("Get Documents method");
    //retorna todos los nomres de los achivos en un listado para cuando yo le de click en otro contenido se actualizen los datos
   return this.http.get(this.URL_API );
  }
  getOneDocument(name: String){
    console.log("Get OneDocyment method name given: " , name);
//este metodo retorna el contenido que tenga el archivo 'name'
    return this.http.get(this.URL_API + `/${name}`)
  }

  postDocument(){
 //falta
  }

  deleteDocument(name:String){
///falta
  }
```

A continuación mostraré el componente documento
Cuando cargue mostrará todos los archivos de una ruta, cuando clickee un li, deberá mostrar el contenido de este mismo

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getDocuments() //aqui extraigo los nombres delos documentos

  }

  getDocuments(){
    this.DocumentService.getDocuments()
        .subscribe(res => {
          this.DocumentService.documents = res as Document[] //un array con el nombre de los documentos

          console.log(res);
        });
  }

//este metodo extrae los datos de el documento dato "name"
  getOneDocument(name : String){
    this.DocumentService.getOneDocument(name)
        .subscribe(res => {
          return  this.DocumentService.documentSelected = res as Document;          
        })

  }
 //este es un metodo de practica, cuando le de click al li deberá cambiar ese paragraph content por lso datos requeridos en el document get one documento que son los datos extraidos pero aqui es donde ocurre el error
  getData(name : String){
    console.log("hola" , name)
    document.getElementById("paragraph_content").innerHTML = this.DocumentService.getOneDocument(name)

  }

}
```

Mi html con el id paragraph content

```
 <nav>
        <ul class="ds-list-unstyled" *ngFor="let document of DocumentService.documents">
            <li><a href="#" (click)="getData(document)"> {{document}}  </a></li>

            <!-- <li><a href=" # ">Supuesto archivo 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="# ">Supuesto archivo 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="# ">Supuesto archivo 3</a></li> -->
        </ul>
    </nav>

   <h2>Texto en pantalla: </h2>
        <p id="paragraph_content">este contenido será cambiado cuando le des click a un nombre de archivo
        </p>
```

Por favor, realmente tengo más de 5 horas con este problema, he estado intentando convertirlo, o como agarrar los datos del array retornado pero siempre me aparece Object o sino el error de observable.
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español! Es una buena primera pregunta, con todo el código bien expuesto, pero nunca viene mal completar el [tour] de bienvenida para ganar tu primera medalla.

Answer (score 1):

El error está en el *método de práctica*:

```
//este es un metodo de practica, cuando le de click al li deberá cambiar ese paragraph content por los datos requeridos en el document get one documento que son los datos extraidos pero aqui es donde ocurre el error
  getData(name : String){
    console.log("hola" , name)
    document.getElementById("paragraph_content").innerHTML = 
        this.DocumentService.getOneDocument(name)

  }
```

Estás intentando poner lo que devuelve el método `getOneDocument` (un `Observable`) como si fuera texto (un `string`).

Lo correcto sería algo así:

```
  getData(name : String){
    console.log("hola" , name)
    this.DocumentService.getOneDocument(name).subscribe(res => {
      document.getElementById("paragraph_content").innerHTML = res;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322) Es erorr que ahora me arrohja,

Comment: La respuesta que estás recibiendo es un Objeto. Por eso te da ese error. Tal vez el dato que necesitas en el elemento DOM es un valor de alguna propiedad de dicho objeto. Antes de asignarlo al elemento, intenta depurar dicha respuesta: *console.dir(res)* y verifica lo que te muestra por consola.

Comment: Usé el res.toString()  

y mande a consola de diferents manera, pero jamás se mete al subscribe solo aparecen los logs de antes de y fuera de, estoy haciendo algo mal?:/
**
getData(name : String){
    console.log("hola" , name)
    // document.getElementById("paragraph_content").innerHTML = this.DocumentService.getOneDocument(name)
    console.log("antes del subscribe");

    this.DocumentService.getOneDocument(name)
        .subscribe( (res ) =>{
          console.log("Dentro del subscribe");
          
        } )

    **console.log("fuera del susbcribe")**


  **}**

Comment: https://imgur.com/CMKxkhC  @MauricioContreras